# Zend Framework: Adding header to form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am trying to add some html to a zend form but I can't find what I want.
So I create the elements then I have this code:

```
$form->addDisplayGroup(array('firstElement', 'secondElement'), 'user', array('legend' => 'My legend'));

$form->setDisplayGroupDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag', array('class'=>'myClass', 'tag' => 'div'))
));
```

I get rid of the fieldset and the legend because it's impossible to style it correctly. So I replace the fieldset with a div, but I need to create a h2 or something to replace the legend. Is there any way to add this in the group decorators?

PS: I know there is a lot of similar questions and I tried them all. It didn't work mainly because I can't add a form element in Zend Framework (I don't have access to the directory to add a class on the server).

Comment: _I get rid of the fieldset and the legend because it's impossible to style it correctly_ Well, that depends on what you understand under 'correctly'. It is very well possible to style fieldset and legend with CSS

Comment: Yes it was a bit stupid to say that this way (I have to admit I was a bit angry because of my problem). What I meant is that I find it really hard to make something 100% cross browser. But it's specific to the design I had to realize and because I had to make it exactly similar from modern browser to IE7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem with the description.
In case anybody has the same issue, here is how I did:

```
$group = $form->getDisplayGroup('nameOfTheGroup');
$group->setDescription('The text you want');
$group->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'myClass')),
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'h2', 'placement' => 'prepend'))
));
```

This will add the description in a h2 tag before the div.